# How can I read and use coordinates from a CSV file in my Quadtree [Python]?

Tags: python, algorithm, quadtree

I am building a Quadtree using python, and have managed to create a solution for randomly generated points. the main class is the QTree class:

```
class QTree():
def __init__(self, treshold, customerCount):
    self.threshold = treshold
    self.points = [Point(random.uniform(0, 100), random.uniform(0, 100)) for x in range(customerCount)]
    self.root = Node(0, 0, 100, 100, self.points)

def add_point(x, y):
    self.points.append(Point(x, y))

def get_points(self):
    return self.points

def subdivide(self):
    recursive_subdivide(self.root, self.threshold)

def graph(self):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    x = [point.x for point in self.points]
    y = [point.y for point in self.points]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    c = find_children(self.root)

    print("\n\nNumber of segments: %d" % len(c))
    areas = set()

    for el in c:
        areas.add(el.width * el.height)
    print("Minimum segment area: %.3f units" % min(areas))

    for n in c:
        ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((n.x0, n.y0), n.width, n.height, fill=False))

    plt.title("Quadtree")
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=3, color='b')
    plt.savefig('QuadtreeDiagram.png', dpi=1000)
    plt.show()
    return
```

I am obtaining my Quadtree diagram (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojYHO.png) by calling the Qtree class and various other def funcitons:

```
def test(treshold, customerCount):
    qt = QTree(treshold, customerCount)
    qt.subdivide()
    qt.graph()


 # Tests
   test(1, 50)
```

My question is: how do I change the random points and use my own CSV file with co-ordinates? Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new function to load the data from file and set the points:

```
 def load_points():

    Df1 = pd.read_csv("D:\\test.txt", sep='\t' )
    self.points=[Point(Df1["Col0"],Df1["Col1"]) for x in range(len(Df1))]
```

Note1: You must get the relation between len of you new data and customerCount
 Note2: I assume that the file is for example like:

Col0    Col1

1        2

2        4

3        5

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by relation? My CSV file is in that format, with a comma between each x and y coordinate. Thank you so much for the help Dayannex

Comment: The number of points is associated with customerCount in the original code